# Query gives wrong output spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I've got a spreadsheet where I wan't to Filter the data from my main sheet Ark1 to another sheet Ark2. In sheet Ark3 I've put an example that works.

I've used a query for the same purpose with a lot of other references, but when using this one all the data from each column is put in the first row?

=Query('Ark1'!A:AH;"Select A,B,C,D,AH where AH is not null")
Put on sheet Ark2!A1

If I for example use the same query but with another set of data it gives the right answer.
=Query('Ark1'!A:Z;"Select A,B,C,D,Z where Z is not null")
I've this one to the sheet Ark3!A1

Doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17QwBLZHtsOFuS-XGHQvCT72XucA8qguVY-lwYcPq69Q/edit#gid=443764035

Comment: I've also tried this one: =Query({'Ark1'!A:AH};"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col34 where Col34 is not null"). With the same problem.

Comment: ...and =Query('Ark1'!A:AH;"Select A,B,C,D,AH where AH !=''"). Same same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column AH contains text values (strings) you'd have to use

```
=Query('Ark1'!A:AH;"Select A,B,C,D,AH where AH !=''"; 1)
```

or

```
=Query('Ark1'!A:AH;"Select A,B,C,D,AH where AH <>''"; 1)
```